# Adobe BlazeDS 4 artifacts maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, adobe, blazeds, artifacts

Does anybody know if Adobe has a maven repository to download the latest BlazeDS artifacts from?
I only can find the "older" versions of BlazeDS in the central mvn repository.

The other option is to deploy the downloaded BlazeDS jar files from the Adobe website into my local repository but it would be nice when Adobe provides the artifacts via a maven repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Adobe does not have a maven repository for BlazeDS. This [thread](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/BLZ-71) can help. You can find BlazeDS 4 in the Spring maven repository: http://s3browse.springsource.com/browse/maven.springframework.org/external/com/adobe/blazeds/

Answer (score 6):

Spring's maven external repository does not contain these artifacts anymore (licencing issue?).

You should download the desired release from [adobe](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Downloads), unzip and `jar -x` the contained war file and at last you must drop all the flex* jars into your local repo with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.adobe.blazeds -Dversion=4.0.0.14931 -DartifactId=blazeds-common -Dfile=flex-messaging-common.jar
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.adobe.blazeds -Dversion=4.0.0.14931 -DartifactId=blazeds-core -Dfile=flex-messaging-core.jar
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.adobe.blazeds -Dversion=4.0.0.14931 -DartifactId=blazeds-opt -Dfile=flex-messaging-opt.jar
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.adobe.blazeds -Dversion=4.0.0.14931 -DartifactId=blazeds-proxy -Dfile=flex-messaging-proxy.jar
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.adobe.blazeds -Dversion=4.0.0.14931 -DartifactId=blazeds-remoting -Dfile=flex-messaging-remoting.jar
mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.adobe.blazeds -Dversion=4.0.0.14931 -DartifactId=blazeds-rds-server -Dfile=flex-rds-server.jar
```

or upload each in your private maven repository (i.e. artifactory or nexus).

**Note**: replace the version with the one you've downloaded

thanks to *pledge*'s [post in flex forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?77454-Using-Spring-BlazeDS-Integration-nightly-builds-with-Maven&p=287589#post287589)

Answer (score 5):

https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-flex/tags/spring-flex-1.5.0.RELEASE/local-repo/ seems to be working.

Add this repo to your pom.xml or settings.xml :

```
<repository>
   <id>SpringFlex</id>
   <name>SpringFlex Source Repo</name>
   <url>https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-flex/tags/spring-flex-1.5.0.RELEASE/local-repo/</url>
</repository>
```

This repository does not include checksums, so you will need to run Maven with the `--lax-checksums` option if you use this repository.

Comment: This is the Spring's integration library for BlazeDS, not the BlazeDS code by Adobe.

Comment: @BenNeill I thought so too, initially, but they actually packaged up the Adobe jars inside their own local repository (note the `local-repo` at the end of the URL), probably because the [BlazeDS Installation Guide](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/blazeds/wiki/BlazeDS%204.0%20Installation%20Guide/) is such a joke.

Answer (score 2):

After lot of searching, i have figured out proper maven repository for Blazeds-4.x.x.

```
<repository>
<id>spring-milestones</id>
<url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/</url>
```

This worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cornel. I added the following snippet to my pom.

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>spring-maven-external</id>
      <name>Springframework Maven External Repository</name>
      <url>http://maven.springframework.org/external</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing blazeds-opt-4.0.0.14931, since it wasn't in the spring repository that srini posted. The following nexus repository provided the jar I needed:

```
<repository>
  <id>NexusThirdParty</id>
  <name>Nexus third party components</name>
  <url>http://zcode.sunji.net/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-flex/tags/spring-flex-1.5.2.RELEASE/local-repo/ seems to be working.

Add this repo to your pom.xml or settings.xml :

```
<repository>
   <id>SpringFlex</id>
   <name>SpringFlex Source Repo</name>
   <url>https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-flex/tags/spring-flex-1.5.2.RELEASE/local-repo/</url>
</repository>
```