# grails install plugin blazeds failed due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: apache-flex, grails, plugins, blazeds, failed-installation

I trying to integrate Flex with Grails through BlazeDS BUT i am stuck with the very first step i.e installing BlazeDS plugin ... it fails everytime i try to install. Following is the complete stacktrace

```
Resolving plugin JAR dependencies ...
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1

==== grailsHome: tried

  D:\Platforms\Grails\grails-1.3.7\lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.xml

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  D:\Platforms\Grails\grails-1.3.7\lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  D:\Platforms\Grails\grails-1.3.7\dist/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.xml

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  D:\Platforms\Grails\grails-1.3.7\dist/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  D:\Platforms\Grails\grails-1.3.7/plugins/grails-flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-flex-messaging-opt/tags/RELEASE_4_0_0_14931_1/grails-flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== grailsCore: tried

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-flex-messaging-opt/tags/RELEASE_4_0_0_14931_1/grails-flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== ebrRelease: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== ebrExternal: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== http://maven.springframework.org/external: tried

  http://maven.springframework.org/external/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://maven.springframework.org/external/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== http://maven.springframework.org/milestone: tried

  http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== ebrRelease: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== ebrExternal: tried

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== http://maven.sinusgear.com/maven_repo: tried

  http://maven.sinusgear.com/maven_repo/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.pom

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  http://maven.sinusgear.com/maven_repo/com/adobe/flex/flex-messaging-opt/4.0.0.14931.1/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1!flex-messaging-opt.jar:

  D:\Work\Personal\Grails\todolist/lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

  C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\blazeds-2.0/lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

  C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\hibernate-1.3.7/lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

  C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\spring-security-acl-1.1/lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

  C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.1/lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

  C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\tomcat-1.3.7/lib/flex-messaging-opt-4.0.0.14931.1.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.1
Failed to install plugin [blazeds-2.0]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies.
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me resolving this issue. Thanks

Comment: I also tried to install the `spring-security-core` and `spring-security-acl` before the blazeds which went successful, but when i try to install blazeds after these two plugins it fails due to the same previous error:
    `:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::  UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES   ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    **:: com.adobe.flex#flex-messaging-opt;4.0.0.14931.1: not found**

[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Akeel\.grails\1.3.7\projects\todolist\plugins\blazeds-2.0
Failed to install plugin [blazeds-2.0]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies.
`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem recently on grails 1.3.7. By somehow this problem was reproduced only in Windows but not in Ubuntu. So i just copy ivy cache from Ubuntu to Windows and now it's ok. I don't know can I place this jars on the internet, so anyway you can manually download them from some maven or ivy repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the repositories section of your BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
mavenRepo "https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-flex/tags/spring-flex-1.5.0.RELEASE/local-repo/"
```

Adapted from this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769574/adobe-blazeds-4-artifacts-maven-repository).

Answer (score 0):

It is Windows' problem. It looks like a corrupt ivy cache. Just delete ivy-cache folder in .grails. For Windows 7, it's: C:\Users[USER NAME].grails\ivy-cache.

It will be regenerated when you use grails command. Hope it helps.